# How to extract Type object from IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, reflection, ienumerable, system.reflection

I have an the following function

```
void Func<T>(IEnumerable<T> e)
{
   // Need type of T here
   Type t = e.CollectionElementsType() ???
}
```

Now to make it more complicated, I have the following code

```
void Func(IEnumerable<object> e)
{
   // Need type of T here
   Type t = e.CollectionElementsType() ???
}
```

Now say I have the following call to the 2nd implementation

```
Func(new List<int>().Cast<object>());
```

I want Func to detect the type int.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want the generic List type or the type of a concrete element in the List? If the last you shouldn't ask for a type but for types.

Comment: Second code snipet does not make sense: `T` is `System.Object`: do you really mean "how to determine the type of objects inside a `IEnumerable<object>`?" then the answer is you have to extract each element in turn and look at it (every element could be a different type).

Comment: @Richard Due to covariance `e` could actually be an `IEnumerable<string>`, or any other type of sequence.

Comment: Your code won't compile. You can't convert `List<int>` to `IEnumerable<object>`. Post some meaningful code

Comment: @Servy: True of course... but assuming that will just be an maintenance problem (ie. either take the non-generic `IEnumerable` or make `Func` generic).

Comment: @Richard Even if func is generic it's possible for the generic argument to still be a less derived version of `T`, i.e. `Func<object>(listOfStrings);`

Comment: @sriram-sakthivel, It was more like a conceptual question to find out if there is a way to detect internal types rather than giving you something you could copy-paste on IDE to compile. For your amusement, I have changed the code, it should compile now.

Comment: @fahadash I've answered for all the possiblities

Answer (score 2):

In the case in the question: `typeof(T)` will work.

More generally reflection can be used on `e` to extract the type parameter—`T`—of `IEnumerable<T>` via [`Type.GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx).

Comment: Would the second method work even when there is no element inside e ?

Comment: @fahadash Yes (both methods do) because they don't depend on the elements, but the type of `e` itself.

Comment: Edited the question. Would the second method work in case of the IEnumerable<object> ?

Comment: @fahadash See my comment on the Q. (Also: better on [SO] to state the whole question up front, the Q&A format doesn't work if you only reveal the real question incrementally).

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing this? :

```
Type t = typeof(T);
```

read more about [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx)

EDIT:

for more complicated case you can have more than one type, so you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes (IEnumerable<object> list)
{
    foreach (object a in list)
    {
       yield return a.GetType();
    }
}
```

if it's really only one type, you can write `Type t = GetTypes(yourEnumerable).FirstOrDefault()`. `GetType()` will get the real type of object.

read about [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx)

Comment: I am only passing one homogeneous types. All I need to get is one single type. Which is sure going to be type of all objects

Answer (score 1):

```
// returns an enumeration of T where o : IEnumerable<T>
public IEnumerable<Type> GetGenericIEnumerables(object o) {
    return o.GetType()
            .GetInterfaces()
            .Where(t => t.IsGenericType == true
                && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Type` of T use this:

```
void Func(IEnumerable<T> e)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
}
```

To get the `Type` of the elements, an alternative is to get the type of the first item (Assuming that all items on list are of the same type):

```
void Func(IEnumerable<T> e)
{
    Type t;
    if(e.Count() > 0){
        t = e.ElementAt(0).GetType();
    }
}
```

Comment: That assumes that there are items; there may not be any.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` does not have a Count property. The underlying concrete type might have but you'll need some form of cast to use it. However not all `IEnumerable<T>` implementations will have such a member.

Comment: And if you iterate the sequence multiple times it may not have the same items, or even the same number of items.  This also break on an infinite sequence, and is ungodly inefficient on really long sequences.